# Swift compare locationInView between LongPress.state

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and I am interested in the IOS gesture. I encountered a problem when I trying to compare the value of locationInView in longPress.state. A little help, please.

```
 func longPressed(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    var iposition: CGPoint?
    var position: CGPoint?
    var startx,starty,endx,endy: CGFloat?

    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {

         iposition = longPress.locationInView(self.view)
        //println(iposition.y)

       // println(iposition!.y)
        goodtext.text = "bad"

    }else if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
         position = longPress.locationInView(self.view)
        goodtext.text = "Good"


    }
    if (position != nil) && (iposition != nil){
        println(position)
        println(iposition)
        println("          ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the value of position an 'iposition' are nil?

Comment: Yes, wether the value of position is nil or the value of iposition is nil